# How to auto scroll the screen up when virtual keyboard appears in react native (on android)

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, textinput, android-virtual-keyboard

The virtual keyboard covers the text inputs and I cannot see what I'm typing. How to avoid this ?
( I tried using KeyboardAwareScrollView but it still covers the text inputs). 
Another issue that I got was an error regarding my styles.container attributes -> justifyContent and alignItems - it said put those inside the ScrollView property - I'm not sure how to do that - I'm new to React native.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container} >
         <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="username"
          placeholderTextColor="#00bcd4"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}  

          />
          <View style={styles.btnContainer}>     
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn}  onPress={() => this.Login(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
                   <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Login</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

with KeyboardAvoidingView also, the same thing:

```
  render() {
    return (
      // <View style={styles.container} >
         <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
         <Text style={styles.heading} >Welcome to SelfCare !</Text>
          <Image
          style={{width: 200, height: 200, marginBottom: 40}}
          source={require('./src/images/icon.png')}
          />
         <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#00bcd4"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}  
             />
         <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#00bcd4"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}  

          />
          <View style={styles.btnContainer}>     
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn}  onPress={() => this.Login(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
                   <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Login</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn}  onPress={() => this.SignUp(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
                   <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Sign Up</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>         
        </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      // </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: keyboard covers textinput]

Answer (score 4):

If you want the screen to go up you could use
**`<KeyboardAvoidingView>`** *instead of* `<KeyboardAwareScrollView>`

it is easier to implement and does the same work unless you want the user to be able to scroll the screen while the keyboard is opened.
`behavior='padding'` << this prop is for the screen how to act. It also takes [height, position] as a value.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">

         ... Your UI ...

   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

or for shorthand you could replace `<View>` with `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` as so:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>

         ... Your UI ...

</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: Tried it, still gives the same :( I've added the code snippet with and the screenshot

Comment: Hey, adding this worked !  ` const keyboardVerticalOffset = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 0

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position' keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset}>
        <ListView .../>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView/>
    ) `